# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined on Deno Deploy

Tags: deno

I'm using [localStorage](https://deno.land/manual@v1.26.1/runtime/web_storage_api) on the server and it works fine locally. But when I deployed my code to Deno deploy is not defined

Do I need to import the localStorage? I Deno.com I couldn't find any docs talking about localStorage so maybe that feature is not supported yet. In that case, where can I deploy my code to use it? Thanks

[image]

```
import {Handlers, PageProps} from "$fresh/server.ts";

interface Data {
 email: string[]
 }

export const handler: Handlers<Data> = {
  GET(_req, ctx) {
    const emailsStorage = localStorage.getItem("email");

    const email = emailsStorage ? JSON.parse(emailsStorage) : [];

    console.log(email);

    return ctx.render({ email });
  },
};

export default function EmailPage({ data }: PageProps<Data>) {
    const { email } = data;
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>Emails</h1>
            <ul>
                {email.map((email) => (
                    <li>{email}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full list of available APIs is [here](https://deno.com/deploy/docs/runtime-api) (note that `localStorage` is not listed).

Deploy does not offer any persistent data storage mechanism. After your deployed code finishes executing in response to a request, all of the JS memory is destroyed, so if you want to work with mutable data that persists between requests, then you'll have to store that data yourself elsewhere — e.g. by sending the data in a network request to another server / hosted database / etc. and then requesting it when you need it.

The [docs](https://deno.com/deploy/docs) include several "persist data" tutorials that you can use as a guide/reference in order to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can persist data in local storage by creating a virtual local Storage by using this code.

```
import { installGlobals } from "https://deno.land/x/virtualstorage@0.1.0/mod.ts";
installGlobals();
```

`localStorage.getItem("email")` will work on Deno Deploy also.